# Webrtc project: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.RendererCommon$YuvUploader'

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm trying build native webrtc app in Android. It works fine until I add either Volley, loopj or facebook-android-sdk to the project via Gradle. I'm unable to figure out what is causing the conflict.

Any suggestion on how this can be resolved ? Thank you!

Here is the full log:

```
01-25 00:48:42.577 25791-25791/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-25 00:48:42.677 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
01-25 00:48:42.677 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 274: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
01-25 00:48:42.677 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
01-25 00:48:42.697 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
01-25 00:48:42.697 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 591: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
01-25 00:48:42.697 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
01-25 00:48:42.747 25791-25831/com.testapp I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
01-25 00:48:42.947 25791-25791/com.testapp I/Adreno200-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.059_msm8960_JB_2.5.5_CL3896081_release_AU (CL3896081)
                                                             Build Date: 06/25/13 Tue
                                                             Local Branch: 
                                                             Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5.5
                                                             Local Patches: NONE
                                                             Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.059 +  NOTHING
01-25 00:48:42.967 25791-25791/com.testapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 00:48:43.127 25791-25791/com.testapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-25 00:48:43.137 25791-25791/com.testapp I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41bac990 time:90636840
01-25 00:48:51.076 25791-25791/com.testapp I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41bac990 time:90644774
01-25 00:49:00.656 25791-25791/com.testapp D/ConnectActivity: Connecting to room 123456789 at URL https://apprtc.appspot.com
01-25 00:49:00.666 25791-25791/com.testapp I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.testapp time:90654362
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.RendererCommon$YuvUploader', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9794 (Lorg/webrtc/RendererCommon$YuvUploader;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000a
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.RendererCommon$YuvUploader', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9794 (Lorg/webrtc/RendererCommon$YuvUploader;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.756 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000a
01-25 00:49:00.796 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36315
01-25 00:49:00.796 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0098
01-25 00:49:00.796 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 36317
01-25 00:49:00.796 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0005
01-25 00:49:00.796 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lorg/webrtc/GlRectDrawer; interface 9791 'Lorg/webrtc/RendererCommon$GlDrawer;'
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/webrtc/GlRectDrawer;' failed
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.init
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9753 (Lorg/webrtc/GlRectDrawer;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer$4', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.release
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9809 (Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer$4;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.806 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002e
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer$5', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.surfaceDestroyed
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9810 (Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer$5;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002d
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer$3', referenced from method org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.tryCreateEglSurface
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9808 (Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer$3;) in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc4f at 0x0c in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc76 at 0x44 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.826 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc77 at 0x4b in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc4f at 0x0c in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc76 at 0x44 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc77 at 0x4b in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.<init>
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dda at 0x9a in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dde at 0xc0 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddd at 0xe6 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.836 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dd9 at 0xe8 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8de0 at 0xea in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddf at 0xec in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddc at 0x15e in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.renderFrameOnRenderThread
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dd9 at 0x0b in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dda at 0x11 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddd at 0x2a in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dd9 at 0x36 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dda at 0x42 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddd at 0x55 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dd9 at 0x57 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.846 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dda at 0x59 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8ddd at 0x5e in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dd9 at 0x62 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8dda at 0x66 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc7b at 0x6c in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.updateFrameDimensionsAndReportEvents
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lorg/webrtc/GlRectDrawer; interface 9791 'Lorg/webrtc/RendererCommon$GlDrawer;'
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/webrtc/GlRectDrawer;' failed
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfb52 at 0x04 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.init
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc79 at 0x30 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.release
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc7a at 0x2f in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.surfaceDestroyed
01-25 00:49:00.856 25791-25791/com.testapp D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfc78 at 0x02 in Lorg/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer;.tryCreateEglSurface
01-25 00:49:00.866 25791-25791/com.testapp E/ActivityThread: Failed to inflate
                                                              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
                                                                  at org.appspot.apprtc.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:160)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                                                                  at org.appspot.apprtc.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:160) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.webrtc.RendererCommon$YuvUploader
                                                                  at org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.<init>(SurfaceViewRenderer.java:69)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                                                                  at org.appspot.apprtc.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:160) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-25 00:49:00.866 25791-25791/com.testapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-25 00:49:00.866 25791-25791/com.testapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41913c80)
01-25 00:49:00.886 25791-25791/com.testapp E/AppRTCDemoActivity: Fatal error: org.webrtc.RendererCommon$YuvUploader
```

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: I stopped using volley